# Optaplanner is not improving the solution, how do I make it change something?

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

In my problem Optaplanner should assign frequencies to TRXs and if two TRXs have the same frequency a Drools rule should fire. I gave it 3 TRXs and 5 frequencies so it should be able to get a perfect solution, but it does not.

This is my first optaplanner project and I tried to follow precisely the instructions in the documentation.

Note: Do not be mislead by the package names, I am not employed by Nokia, this is a uni project

Project is here:
https://github.com/batam1414/nokiaboy

for the reader class
band file has the following content:

```
100 105 1
```

trx file has the following content:

```
1 1
2 3 
2 1 
1 3
3 1
1 2
```

the code is quite simple but if you need any explanations please let me know

I would expect optaplanner to give every trx a different frequency since there are 3 TRXs and 5 frequencies, this way all rules are OK and the score should be 0.

However optaplanner just gives every TRX the first frequency.

Help please.

Comment: Change something manually and have it calculate the score. Is the score better?

Comment: I figured it out, my drools rules were bad, thank you.